# Chrome removes event listeners?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm making a tool and I'm trying to have file drag and drop features in it. 
It works in every browser except for Chrome, BUT it does work in Chrome when it's local.

I have this piece of code to define the events:

```
   document.ondragenter =
   document.ondragleave = dragenterDragleave;
   document.ondragover = function(evt) { evt.preventDefault() };
   document.ondrop = drop;
```

As the script ends, the events are there. But Chrome keeps on processing other bits of code, and eventually just removes the events. Why is this happening?

**Edit|** I just found out this is a problem on my computer. But it's happening to several of my friends as well, using chrome. It might be an extension that's running but that shouldn't be a problem.

I asked my friends if they could turn off ad block, and that apparently fixes it.

Comment: Add a JS fiddle example

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that with what's happening. But you can test it out here: http://www.stepperman.me/imagefun/

Comment: I got main.js:40 Uncaught ReferenceError: copyTextToClipboard is not defined
    at FileReader.filereader.onloadend (main.js:40)

Comment: Sorry that's leftover code from my debugging. It should work now. I also edited the post because I found out something new.

Comment: What was the problem you actually found?

Comment: I turned off all the extensions, and it works now. I tried it with a single extension turned on, trying out every single one I have installed and it still works. It must be a combination of extensions, I think.

Comment: You're not the first tone have a mystery problem caused by chrome extensions :). Add that as the answer and mark it correct, so those looking to answer questions tonight don't end up reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. Adblock (specifically uBlock Origin..) doesn't like it when there are event listeners on the document root. So I just wrapped it all up in a wrapper and added the event listeners to that instead and it works now!

So if you ever run into this problem and use event listeners on the document, or body. Change it to a wrapper. This *should* fix it.